# Number theory question: Prove $27\mid a+b+c$ if $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)=a+b+c$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Integers $a,b$ and $c$ satisfy $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)=a+b+c$. Prove $27\mid a+b+c$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It has been pointed out to me in the comments section of my answer that it wouldn't be right on my part to directly give answers, rather than hints initially. I apologize for the same. Moreover, I request you to ensure that you edit your question to include your initial work, progress and thoughts on the problem. I also request you to follow these guidelines for any future questions. MSE strongly believes that a good question must include such content. This would reduce the number of downvotes that your questions receive.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking me into consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, assume that $3 \nmid (a+b+c)$. Then, $3 \nmid (a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$, which means that $a,b,c$ must be distinct modulo $3$. However, we still get $a+b+c \equiv 0+1+2 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ which is a contradiction. Thus, $3 \mid (a+b+c)$, and thus $3 \mid (a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$.

WLOG let $3 \mid (a-b)$. It then follows that:
$$3 \mid (a+b+c) \implies 3 \mid (a-b)+(2b+c) \implies 3 \mid (2b+c) \implies b \equiv c \pmod{3}$$

Thus, we get $a \equiv b \equiv c \pmod{3}$. This means that each of the factors $(a-b),(b-c),(c-a)$ is divisible by $3$. Hence:
$$27 \mid (a-b)(b-c)(c-a) \implies 27 \mid (a+b+c)$$
Hence, proved.

Comment: Could the downvoter please justify their cause of downvoting the answer? If there is anything that could improve the answer, I would be happy to make the required edits.

Comment: Excellent answer. But you could have given some hints first, because OP has not given his attept at all.

Comment: @A.Sharma My apologies, I'll make sure I do the same next time onward...

Comment: @Haran I didn't downvote, so I don't know for sure why that person did it, but I've seen downvotes fairly often for answers (especially full ones as opposed to ones just giving hints), with no apparent mistakes, when they are for blatant PSQ (Problem Statement Question) type questions, i.e., ones showing no attempts or effort. Since I don't see anything technically wrong with your answer (although I agree with A. Sharma it might have been better for you to have given some hints instead of a full answer as the OP didn't show any attempts), this is a definite possible reason for your downvote.